# Proof that a solution to an ODE is null

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Given a matrix $A_{n \times n}$ with real entries and $z(t)$ a solution to $\dot{x} = f(x)$ such that $|| z(t) || \leq Me^{-t^2}$, $\forall t \geq 0$, $M > 0$ constant. Show that $z(t) \equiv 0$.

My attempt:

Observe that $z(t) = e^{At} x$, $x$ being the initial condition. We can write $e^{At}$ in the form $e^{At} =\{ c_{ij}e^{d_{ij}t}p_{ij}(t) \}$ where $c_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}$ are constants and $p_{ij}(t)$ is polynomial.

Using the following norm:

$$
||z(t)|| = {\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}} | \sum_{j=0}^n c_{ij}e^{d_{ij}t}p_{ij}(t)x_j|
$$

From $|| z(t) || \leq Me^{-t^2}, \forall t \geq 0$ we get:

$$
\max |\sum_{j=0}^n c_{ij}e^{d_{ij}t}p_{ij}(t)x_j|e^{t^2} \leq M \Rightarrow \max |\sum_{j=0}^n c_{ij}e^{d_{ij}t + t^2}p_{ij}(t)x_j| \leq M \phantom{aaaaaaaaa}(1)
$$

Suppose $x \neq 0 $, taking the limit yields:

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \max | \sum_{j=0}^n c_{ij}e^{d_{ij}t + t^2}p_{ij}(t)x_j| = \infty
$$

Which is a contradiction to (1). And so $x \equiv 0$.

Did i do something wrong? I'm not sure if this is correct.